# Extra frame with BOXED option in package floatrow

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow, frame

I was testing the package `floatrow` because I need create a frame around my figures including the corresponding caption. The next example was got from the very package `floatrow` (of course, I added figure and caption)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
%showframe
]{geometry}
\geometry{
    margin=2.54cm
}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\floatsetup{style=BOXED,valign=t}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[75]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{floatrow}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth+2cm]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
        {\caption{This is a bit long caption to see if it fits or not in the box}}
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get the desired frame but an unwanted frame is added above the image. I don't really know why is happening this. I'm adding an extra image to explain the result.

[image]

I know that this behaviour is due to `\ffigbox[\FBwidth+2cm]`, but if I remove it, the frame "overflows from the margins". I would like to know if there is someway of solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't need that package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
%showframe
]{geometry}
\geometry{
margin=2.54cm
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[75]
\begin{figure}[h]     
\centering\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth+2cm}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth-2cm]{example-image}
\caption{This is a bit long caption to see if it fits or not in the box}    
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. This approach seems me most comfortable, although @Dario 's one looks well.

Comment: @MichaelRosalesVilca you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

my be using the package `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    %\floatsetup{style=BOXED,valign=t}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\graphicspath{{/home/darioslc/figuritex/} {/home/darioslc/figuritex/eps/}}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum[75]
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=6cm,align=center]
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image
        \caption{This is a bit long caption to see if it fits or not in the box}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Do not could work for me the package `floatrow`, that's why I comment.

[image]

Regards!
Darío